# Compile all C files in all of the children directories

Tags: c, gcc, raylib

So, I'm making a game with raylib and I need to compile all the .c files at once.

The files are in separate folder inside the 1st one(Like "MainFolder/PlayerFiles").

I know how that `gcc -o game *.c  -L/usr/local/lib -lraylib` compiles all the files inside the directory and creates a exec.

How can I compile all the .c files in all of the children folders.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Write one `gcc` command for each C file? Put them in a script? Write a script that files all the C files and executes a command to compile each one? Write a makefile with a pattern rule to compile a C file give it a list of all the C files? Install a GUI IDE and add all the C files to a project in it?

Comment: I used an IDE. Even tho all the files are compiled correctly, when you executed the output outside the IDE, it only runs the main.c file.

Comment: Re “Even tho all the files are compiled correctly,…”: So all the files are compiled. Yet this question asks how to compile all the files. So the question you asked is a solved problem; it is not what you really want to ask.

Comment: Re “… when you executed the output outside the IDE, it only runs the main.c file”: This is a different problem. Your program is not working the way you want. That is what you should have asked about. We do not know what it means to only run “the main.c file”. C programs start with `main`, and it is the job of the `main` routine to call other routines. So, if that is not happening, there is something wrong in your `main` routine or one or more of the routines it calls. To solve that, you have to narrow down what is wrong. Then maybe you can ask about that.

Comment: I think the question is this - "I can compile this large project in my IDE, but not from the command line". Is that right? If so, what IDE? In many cases the IDE will have created the files needed to automate the build

Comment: What you say “you executed the output outside the IDE, it only runs the main.c file”, what is “the output”? Is that the executable file that is the result of building inside the IDE, so you try to execute the build product? Or is “the output” some build script or makefile or something similar that the IDE provides for you to use to build from the command line? What does “only runs the main.c file” mean? Does that mean only the main.c file is compiled? Or only some function inside the main.c file is executed?